# Include a file before current template file

Tags: template-redirect

I would like to include two files before and after current template.
I am using template_redirect to do this,

But when I call `get_current_template()` inside `template_redirect` it returns nothing.

is there a way to solve this ??

**here is my code:**

```
// current template file
add_filter( 'template_include', 'var_template_include', 1000 );
function var_template_include( $t ){
    $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'] = basename($t);
    return $t;
}

function get_current_template() {
    if( !isset( $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'] ) )
        return false;
    if( $echo )
        echo $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'];
    else
        return $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'];
}

// use template redirect to include file
add_action('template_redirect', 'ra_template_block');
function ra_template_block() {
        include_once THEME_DIR.'/blockstop.php';
    get_template_part(get_current_template());      
    include_once THEME_DIR.'/blocks.php';
    exit;
}
```

**Way I am doing this**
I want to set page layout from a file. I need to include below tags every time in my template file:

- `get_header()`
- `get_footer()`
- `get_sidebar()`
- `get_template_part('right')`
- `get_template_part('left')`

So if I can set them from a specific file, then I dont need to include them in every template file.

Comment: got solution, i need to use `template_include` instead of `template_redirect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template_redirect` runs *before* `template_include`. You can demonstrate that with this:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'var_template_include', 1000 );
function var_template_include( $t ){
  echo __FUNCTION__;
}
// use template redirect to include file
add_action('template_redirect', 'ra_template_block');
function ra_template_block() {
  echo __FUNCTION__;  
}
```

Or you could just look at the source: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/template-loader.php

Since your code `exit`s in `template_redirect` the `global` that `get_current_template` depends upon never gets set, and even if you didn't `exit` it would be set too late.

You need the template path passed into `template_include` so if you just hook both filters to that hook and give them a priority so that the one always loads before the other this should work, at least insofar as setting and retrieving that `global`.

```
// current template file
add_filter( 'template_include', 'var_template_include', 1000 );
function var_template_include( $t ){
  var_dump($t);
  $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'] = basename($t);
  return $t;
}

// use template redirect to include file
add_action('template_include', 'ra_template_block', 1001);
function ra_template_block() {
//     include_once THEME_DIR.'/blockstop.php';
    var_dump(get_template_part(get_current_template()));      
//     include_once THEME_DIR.'/blocks.php';
    exit;
}
```

Of course, there is no real reason for two filters. One would do just as well.