# How to change a specific page to custom page?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want to change specific page so that non-member users will be faced with a form that they can register with, and also this page wouldn't look like the others, I mean this page must be totally different to other pages because of my HTML code. 
But I don't have any idea how to implement it. 
For example in my plugin I wrote this code:

```
function ok() {
if (is_page('get-messages')){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        echo "$role<br>";
    }
    echo get_settings('siteurl') . '/get-messages';
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        ?>
        <form method="get" action="">
        <input type="submit" value="ok">
        </form>
        <?php
    }   
}

} 
add_action('template_redirect', 'ok');
```

what i must write in `if(!is_user_logged_in())` so that my plugin don't let to page loads its template and only show my html code.
I appreciate your help

Comment: Please explain your question more deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a custom page template.

1. Create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates).
2. In that page template paste your code.
3. Create a "Page" from wp_admin->Pages and select your template file as the "Template"

In your page template, you would have something like this:

```
/*
Template Name: My Custom HTML Page
*/
get_header();

get_footer();
```

Leave out the `get_header` and `get_footer` and you will have a page that loads in WordPress but without most of the theme structure.

Comment: this is good but i want do this with plugin not template

Comment: Then use `template_redirect` or `template_include` to load the code-- [like this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105595/21376). If you want more help, [edit] the question to be more descriptive of the problem. As written, answering your question is basically guesswork.

Comment: thanks. with your help and tutorial in this [link](http://www.mihaivalentin.com/wordpress-tutorial-load-the-template-you-want-with-template_redirect/) I've made a specific page.